# String DataColunm in DataTable :Limiting the length of the string

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

I have a requirement whihc I have to set a limit on the length of a string.

If the length excedes the limit then i want to truncate the string. I doing it DataTable and adding string DataColumns.

Comment: What is the consumer of the DataTable?  How is it being presented?

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this would work...

> myStr = myStr.Length > maxLen ? myStr.Substring(0, maxLen) : myStr;

Depending on what your code looks like; you might need to make sure myStr isn't null before you evaluate this line.  But, if myStr is longer than the max Length, it gets truncated; otherwise you my myStr.

MyStr.Length will fail if myStr is null.

This would be done as strings are added to the DataTable.

If you want to truncate strings that are already in the dataTable, I might be misunderstanding the question.  You can set the .MaxLength property on the dataColumn, but I believe that will not truncate data.

Comment: I am inserting from to another, while inserting to another table i want to truncate the sting to the max length.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't DataColumn have a MaxLengh property?  I've not tried it out but shouldn't it work?

Comment: It does; but I believe it only throws an exception.  It won't truncate.